# How to refer to the outer class this?

Tags: groovy, inner-classes

I've been searching in the [official Groovy documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_creating_instances_of_non_static_inner_classes) how to replace a call like

```
MyOuterClass.this
```

inside a nested class MyInnerClass, but they don't seem to talk about this difficulty. And I did not find by Googling neither.

So, let's say I have this code :

```
class MyOuterClass {
    class MyInnerClass {
    }
}
```

How can I call the this pointer of MyOuterClass inside a method of MyInnerClass ?

Here is an attempt :

```
public class Outer {
    def sayHello() {println "Hello !"}
    public class Inner {
        def tellHello(){
            Outer.this.sayHello()
        }
    }
}

def objOuter = new Outer()
def objInner = new Outer.Inner()
objInner.tellHello()
```

and here the error stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sayHello() on null object
    at Outer$Inner.tellHello(inner_outer.groovy:5)
    at Outer$Inner$tellHello.call(Unknown Source)
    at inner_outer.run(inner_outer.groovy:12)
```

(I am using the Groovy 2.4.5 version).

Comment: Can you post the code that fails, and the exception you get?

Comment: As it is in large android activity class (translated into Groovy from a Java code), I am trying to get a more simple example. Then I'll edit my question.

Comment: I've added a snippet illustrating my difficulty and its stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that you're not passing the outer object to your new Inner class statement, use this:

```
def objOuter = new Outer()
def objInner = new Outer.Inner(objOuter)
```

Instead of:

```
def objOuter = new Outer()
def objInner = new Outer.Inner()
```

And your code will works,

Hope this helps,